# How to extract certain words from a php string?

Tags: php, string

I have a long string like this `I1:1;I2:2;I8:2;NA1:5;IA1:[1,2,3,4,5];S1:asadada;SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];`. Now I just want to get certain words like 'I1','I2','I8','NA1' and so on i.e. words between ':'&';'  only ,and store them in array. How to do that efficiently?

I have already tried using `preg_split()` and it works but giving me wrong output. As shown below.

```
// $a is the string I want to extract words from
$str = preg_split("/[;:]/", $a);
print_r($str);
```

The output I am getting is this

```
Array
(
    [0] => I8
    [1] => 2
    [2] => I1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => I2
    [5] => 2
    [6] => I3
    [7] => 2
    [8] => I4
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => NA1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => IA1
    [1] => [1,2,3,4,5]
    [2] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => S1
    [1] => asadada
    [2] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => SA1
    [1] => [1,2,3,4,5]
    [2] => 
)
```

But I am expecting 'I8','I1','I2','I3','I4' also in seperated array with position [0]. Any help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is using a combination of [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). The result is returned as a string, but you can easily put it into an array for example.

```
<?php
$input = "I1:1;I2:2;I8:2;NA1:5;IA1:[1,2,3,4,5];S1:asadada;SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];.";
$output = array();

$array = explode(";", $input);
foreach($array as $item) {
   $output[] = explode(":", $item)[0];
}    

echo implode(",", $output);
?>
```

Output:

```
I1,I2,I8,NA1,IA1,S1,SA1,SA1,.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like.

```
<?php

$str = 'I1:1;I2:2;I8:2;NA1:5;IA1:[1,2,3,4,5];S1:asadada;SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];';

preg_match_all('/(?:^|[;:])(\w+)/', $str, $result);

print_r($result[1]);  // Matches are here in $result[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a greedy match to match the items between `;` and `:` using [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php

$str = 'I1:1;I2:2;I8:2;NA1:5;IA1:[1,2,3,4,5];S1:asadada;SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];SA1:[1,2,3,4,5];';

preg_match_all('/;(.+?)\:/',$str,$matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Live Demo:** https://3v4l.org/eBsod